# About installation off of dvd on to a NTFS partition

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

I have a 81gb partition on my 500gb hard drive where I want to install ubuntu but don't know how using "something else" option. Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

## Installing to NTFS is not supported

Unfortunately, NTFS does not support Unix/Linux file permissions and thus it is impossible to install Ubuntu on an NTFS partition. You would have to delete/shrink your NTFS partition and create a new EXT4 or some other supported partition(Ext4 is good for most purposes).

Since I cannot answer your original question, I can provide the next best alternative.

## Alternative Solution

1. Shrink your NTFS partition
2. Create a new Ext4 partition
3. In the installer, set it's mount point as "/".
4. (optional) Create a swap partition(like, a place for ram-dump if ram gets full, to simply put it.)
5. Continue with installation as usual. You'd be done.

Refer to this link as well: [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

## An Experiment

What I'm describing below is **not at all** practical and recommended. If you're interested in this for experimenting, you should [read what this person did](https://brainder.org/2011/11/29/installing-linux-in-a-file-in-an-ntfs-partition/) to *run* Linux on NTFS. To sum it up in short:

1. Create a big file in an NTFS partition.
2. Format that file as an Ext4 partition.
3. Mount the file as a drive in the installer.
4. Install Linux to the virtual partition. In short, install Linux to the file.
5. Use something like [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) at boot time to select to boot from the *file* in which Linux is installed.

There. You have Linux inside an NTFS drive. I'm not sure how mounting the original drive would work put and what the security and practical implications of this would be, but it is possible, to say the least.